# At least one object must implement IComparable in Min()

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the following LINQ to get 6 `Offer` that have Min `ListPrice` and whose OfferCode contains "dtv" but I get the following exception

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

Here is my code:

```
List<Offer> dtvOffers = 
         offerList.Where(x => (x.ListPrice == offerList.Min(y=>y.ListPrice)) && 
                         (x.OfferCode.ToLower().Contains("dtv")))
         .Take(6)
         .ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the type of the `ListPrice` property? Does it implement `IComparable`?

Comment: What type is `ListPrice`.

Comment: "Here is my code" -- no, it isn't ... it doesn't include the definition of `Offer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is `offerList.Min(y => y.ListPrice)`.

It seems your `ListPrice` is a custom type and hence system cannot differentiate its `min` or `max`. You need to implement `IComparable` in your `ListPrice` and its code to remove this error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides with the use of the `Min()` function. Because you are using your own class (presumably) to perform the query, Linq needs to know exactly how to do a comparison to know which object in the List is the Minimum. To do so you will have to implement the `IComparable` interface on your `Offer` class and write the custom comparison method.

Here's a guide - https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/help/320727/how-to-use-the-icomparable-and-icomparer-interfaces-in-visual-c

Another idea (if you don't want to go down the `IComparable` route) would be to sort the collection using `OrderBy()` and specify the property on your offer class you want to use for the comparison, then use `First()` to pick the the first in the list after the sort.

Comment: Thanks for the Edits @MickyD :-)

Comment: You are quite welcome good sir.  :)